# How to assign values or access value of the variables that are local to function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, local-variables

I am running test for angular app through jasmine. I want to know , How to assign values or access value of the variables that are local to function?

Comment: Can you paste some code that you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't test it because it is gone after the call. 
they are scoped to the method closure,**

1. Declare them globally `globallyDeclaredvariable: boolean;` in your
   class
2. Use them with `this.globallyDeclaredvariable = true;` inside your
   method
3. Then you can write
   `expect(component.globallyDeclaredvariable).toBeTruthy();` in your
   tests.